# Add navigation to existing view controllers / segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several ViewController chained together with segue in a simple hierarchy.

In each of them :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myController" sender:myVar];

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myController"]){
        MyController *controller = (MyController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.myVar = sender;
    }
}
```

**I'm looking for the simplest way to integrate a top navigation bar with a back button**. I know I can use something like this in `viewWillAppear` :

```
   UINavigationBar *myNav = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)];
    [self.view addSubview:myNav];
```

But in this case the navigation bar hides a part of the view (like a "position:absolute" would in css).

I can add a Navigation Controller which solves the problem above but from what I understand this will make my segue useless, which I don't want.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. You can embed the first controller in a navigation controller, and make your segues "Show" if they're not already.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the `prepareForSegue` method ? This only way I know is `showViewcontroller`.

Comment: prepareForSegue is used for preparing the next view controller. It has nothing to do with performing the segue, or what type the segue is, so I'm not sure what you're asking. The only thing you need to do is embed your first controller in a navigation controller, and change the type of your segues if they're not already "Show" type (or "Push" if you're not using size classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `UINavigationController` is for. Your first view controller (called the root) is embedded in a navigation controller. Additional view controllers are then pushed onto the navigation controller.

UINavigationController automatically manages the navigation bar on the top and creates the back button for you.

Once you have embedded your view controller in a navigation controller, you can use push segues.

[image: Push Segues]

Comment: I had to do this through the editor menu, I couldn't delete the table view inserted when using the Objects library.

Comment: Right, for anyone else reading: you can add a UINavigationController to an existing UIViewController through Editor -> Embed in -> UINavigationController